# Runtime error when using struct as value in std::map?

Tags: c++, struct, runtime-error, stdmap

I am using a map with int value -> trie, trie is the struct. So why am I getting runtime error when I print all keys value in my map? But if I don't print anything then there is no error(the insert() part don't cause any error).

```
struct trie{
    node *root;
    trie(){
        root = new node();
    }
    void insert(int x){
        node *cur = root;
        for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--){
            int b = (x >> i) & 1;
            if (cur->child[b] == NULL) cur->child[b] = new node();
            cur = cur->child[b];
        }
        cur->isleaf = true;
    }
    int maxxor(int x){
        node *cur = root;
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--){
            int b = (x >> i) & 1;
            if (cur->child[b ^ 1] != NULL){
                res |= (1ll << i);
                cur = cur->child[b ^ 1];
            } 
            else cur = cur->child[b];
        }
        return res;
    }
    int minxor(int x){
        node *cur = root;
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--){
            int b = (x >> i) & 1;
            if (cur->child[b] != NULL) cur = cur->child[b];
            else{
                res |= (1ll << i);
                cur = cur->child[b ^ 1];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    ~trie(){
        delete root;
    }
};
map<int, trie> tr;
int32_t main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    tr[3].insert(1);// no error
    for(auto x: tr) cout << x.first << ' '; //RUNTIME ERROR?
}
```

I have tried to debug and read various questions/answers but I still not be able to debug this code. Any help are appreciated.

Comment: this is asking for segfaults,

Comment: Your code is not complete (eg. Struct node is not here), and we don't have the error message...

Comment: what is `node`? My guess would be that copying the map elements causes the problem (in `for (auto x:tr)`)

Comment: don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`

Comment: node is a also a struct to function the trie

Comment: btw `for (auto & x : tr)` would probably fix the runtime error for now, but still you have to fix the `trie`

Comment: here my code in ideone: http://ideone.com/VysafQ

Comment: in question please

Comment: thanks @tobi303 you're right, if I add the '&' symbol the code will run perfectly, but why?

Comment: @KienPham please read the full comment. You have to fix `trie` and the `node`! Currently you allow to copy instances, but any code that creates a copy is broken. Adding the `&` is just a quick and dirty fix and does not address the actual problem. In  `for( auto x : tr)`  `x` is a copy of the map elements but in `for (auto & x : tr)` `x` is a reference

Comment: what do you mean by creates a copy ?

Comment: I mean `for (auto x : tr)` expands to something that copies `node`s. Sorry, in my previous comments I mixed stuff up a little bit: Your `trie` is broken and cannot be copied and apparently the same is true for your `node` (and this is what caused the runtime error, but both have to be fixed)

Comment: btw as it stands your question should be closed, because the problem is in `node` that you dont show here

Comment: I don't know what the entire code is (node struct is missing) so my guess is that:

tr[3].insert(1).
Try replacing this with:
tr[3] = new trie;
tr[3].insert(1);

Comment: tr[3] all by itself already causes map to default construct an instance. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at "Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist."  The fault lies in trie and node, as already stated.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented a "complex" tree if i may say, using linked list. And in order to avoid trouble, you need to make sure that your destructors do their work propoerly and are coherent i.e destroy all allocated memory and don't "try" to "destroy" unallocated space or already destroyed space.

That said, your trie destructor destroys root data member, which calls node destructor. And node destructor destroys both two child which were not necessarily allocated. This is the origin of your Segmentation Error.

To correct this you should only destroy allocated child. 
Here is a simplified version of your code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int int64_t
using namespace std;
struct node{
    node* child[2];
    bool isleaf;

    node(){
        child[0] = child[1] = NULL;
        isleaf = false;
    }

    ~node(){            
    }
};
struct trie{
    node *root;
    trie(){
        cout << " in trie ctor" << endl;
        root = new node();
    }

    void insert(int x){
        cout << "in insert trie methode " << endl;

        node *cur = root;

        cur->child[0] = new node();
        cur->child[1] = new node();

    }

    ~trie(){
        delete root->child[0]; // i'm sure it has been allocated
        delete root->child[1]; // i'm sure it has been allocated
        // delete root, would be like doing int *p; delete p;
    }
};

map<int, trie> tr;
int32_t main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    tr[3].insert(1);
    for(auto x: tr) 
        cout << x.first << endl << endl;    
}
```